# Can you help me understanding this transaction on Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan, uniswap

I am following [a16z](https://a16z.com/)'s activity [on etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x05e793ce0c6027323ac150f6d45c2344d28b6019#tokentxns).

In the image, you can see they are purchasing many [OpenSea Metaverse tokens](https://etherscan.io/token/0x2d06a9d454c80a39513a550e0e01747b51d84d65?a=0x05e793ce0c6027323ac150f6d45c2344d28b6019). I can see it is through [this liquidity pool](https://v2.info.uniswap.org/pair/0xe9442dcd1565e8dad778bb09d3186cb5794a1193) on Uniswap.

I was trying to purchase some tokens as an experiment and I was wondering why it is not possible. Can liquidity pools be private? I have also tried to increase the slippage.

[image: opensea metaverse transaction]

Btw, what do these transactions represent in your opinion? I have seen many recently. Look at [Twitter Metaverse](https://etherscan.io/token/0xfb36248a7d9cddf1a685f7da1147eca08d2edf11?a=0xAb5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B), [Amazon Metaverse](https://etherscan.io/token/0xa04e18e86408fa651c144f10de5236493d070e78?a=0x05e793ce0c6027323ac150f6d45c2344d28b6019), [Hollywood Metaverse](https://etherscan.io/token/0x4ecdd145c5a2c9bf688e51a7240827e07433c06e?a=0x05e793ce0c6027323ac150f6d45c2344d28b6019)...

Comment: How do you know that the address belong to a16z? Obviously it is tagged on etherscan as such, but how reliable is that information?

Comment: Of course I am not 100% sure. I have been following this account for same time. The huge holding in MKR is a good indication. Also, their 374k SNX tokens are mentioned in this article from 2019: https://synthetix.community/blog/2019/12/29/a16z-investment